# Eclipse cannot run Spock tests with source folder disappearing

Tags: eclipse, maven, groovy, eclipse-plugin, spock

I've encountered a very curious case about Eclipse and Spock tests. 
I have Eclipse 4.5.2 (Build id: 20160218-0600) with Groovy compilers plugins installed, Groovy-Eclipse M2E Integration and Groovy-Eclipse Feature, all in version: **2.9.2.xx-201604081629-e45**.
In this Eclipse I have a maven project configured to compile and run Spock tests. In Eclipse I have src/test/groovy folder configured as a source folder and it is holding my spock tests. Both maven and Eclipse can run the tests just fine.

Recently my friend has had a problem with the same setup, so I tried to reproduce it. And now I have the same Eclipse 4.5.2 (Build id: 20160218-0600) with Groovy plugin (and this is the weird part, I used the same update site for these plugins but the build version is different, it is: **2.9.2.xx-201607251752-e45**). I imported the same maven project, however, when I try to run Spock tests the curious thing happens: the src/test/groovy source folder dissappears from the project and on the console I can see ClassNotFoundException with the name of the Spock test class. Here is a short summary how it looks like:

[image]

We tried the same also in Eclipse Neon and Spring STS and we have the same result. (In IntelliJ the same project runs just fine).
I'm starting ti thing that this may be related to the Groovy plugins, which might have got changed in the latest build and a bug was introduced. However, I hope I am mistaken.

Any thoughts?